# Flutter + Firebase. Sorting data in chronological order

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I add some data to the collection. When i retrive it, it is sorted by that  generated id. Is it posible to make firebase to sort it in chronological order or it is required to add one more field with date and sort it once it is retrived in flutter?

Comment: why not use orderBy in the query?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you need a `createdAt` timestamp field and use it like

```
Firestore.instance
     .collection("users")
     .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true or false).getDocuments()
```

And you can store `createdAt` on flutter side with `Timestamp` (Its included in `cloud_firestore`), and you can get current timestamp with `Timestamp.now()`

Comment: getting error in console: "Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here...." any suggestion, thanks.

Comment: You should create index by following the link, when we use order feature, firestore needs to create index for performance.

Comment: Its weird to create index by console url suggested by firebase but I had created index. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in metadata on when a document was inserted. If you want to order the documents by insertion order, you will indeed have to add a field with that information yourself and order on that field when retrieving the documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you have stored ID then you can sort them by **id** these are generated by firebase using the timestamp.